# Question about setting up FIle Writer in C#

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

Im using DirectShowLib in C#. I want to use File Writer in C# to set a file output. I want to use File Writer because Graph.SetOutputFileName() wont connect to my encoder, but File Writer will. How can i set the File that File Writer saves to in C#?

I tried pulling up its property pages like in the DxPropPages example but one won't come up for File Writer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pulled from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/4e986aca-bac6-4c8d-ab10-8811c32983d2/)

```
IBaseFilter ibf = new FileWriter() as IBaseFilter;
```

Update:

> "I know how to add file writer to my
>   graph in code i just dont know how to
>   set the file path"

try the following:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter();
IFileSinkFilter fileSinkFilter = (IFileSinkFilter)fileWriter;
fileSinkFilter.SetFileName(fileOutput, null);
```

Here a useful link that shows a full running [example](http://www.informikon.com/directshow-tutorials/using-directshow-editing-services-des-with-c.html). the example is demonstrating the use of DES but you should get the general idea from it.

Comment: how does that let me set up a file for FileWriter?  I know how to add file writer to my graph in code i just dont know how to set the file path

Comment: @Grant: Sorry, I misunderstand your question.

Comment: in graphedit, inserting the File Writer filter brings up a dialog box to select where you want to save a file. In code, no option like that exists that i know of :(

Comment: @Grant: try this "I hope it will help this time :)":                                                           `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter();
IFileSinkFilter fileSinkFilter = (IFileSinkFilter)fileWriter;
fileSinkFilter.SetFileName(fileOutput, null);`

Comment: I think thats getting closer :) i did that and said .SetFileName("C:\name.txt",null)and also .SetFileName("C:\\name.txt", null) and it created an AccessViolationException when i tried to do MediaControl.Run()

Comment: i tried making a filesinkfilter, setting its filename then converting it to a filewriter and didnt work too well, or maybe i just did it wrong.

Comment: ^__________________________________^  works in the simple case, shall require more testing